# Using arrays to look for specific last characters in excel

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula

I have two excel columns: column A contains numbers and column B contains values.

I want to look for a specific cell on column A, which contains a number that ends with specific 2 digits - and copy the value of its neighbor on column B.

I used arrays and the function RIGHT, but unfortunately was unsuccessful.

For example, these are the columns:

```
 A     B
1234   1
1545   2
179    3
```

Cell C1 contains:

```
=(RIGHT(A:A,2)*1 = 45)*B:B
```

I clicked `Ctrl+Shift+Enter` and it was supposed to return 2, but for some reason it won't work.
The strange thing is that it does work with '34' and the first line.

Can you please help me determine the problem?

Comment: Just to be clear, you have a 2 digit number and you want to compare that 2 digit number with all column A last 2 digits and if there is a match you want to display next columns corresponding value. I have 2 questions. 1: are you planning to have this formula in every cell of column C or only 1 formula to look all of them? 2: if you want 1 formula to look all column A, what happens if there are more then 1 match?

Comment: Hi @Dubison, 1. I want this formula just on cell C1. 2. I make sure there are no duplicates.

Comment: see my answer below please. That is what you wanted.

Comment: you can use `=LOOKUP(45,RIGHT(A:A,2)*1,B:B)` as I mentioned in my answer below. Please let me know if it works out.

Answer (score 0):

you can use below IF formula which accept three argument.

```
=IF(RIGHT(A:A,2)*1 = 45,B1,66)
```

1. first args : condition
2. second args : if true then copy neighbor cell value
3. third args: if false then display value appropriately

Comment: Thank you, but this solution works only for the second row. I'm looking for a general formula

Answer (score 0):

On top of @TechnoCrat s answer, if you want to use only 1 cell which will go through all columnA and return you the corresponding value in columnB you can use following formula. Which will result as the picture.

[image]

I used "$C$1" as the variable where you may want to input your 2 digit number you want to search or you can simply change that in the code with the number you desire.

```
=LOOKUP($C$1,RIGHT(A:A,2)*1,B:B)
```

Comment: It worked. For some reason, when I tried to duplicate the formula for more cells (like you mentioned in your comment) it didn't work, so I ended up using INDEX MATCH. Thanks a lot!

Comment: ok, thanks for the feedback. If you want to use it just let me know what kind of problem you are facing otherwise good luck with your index match :P